# Rummikub algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, artificial-intelligence

We're creating a Rummmikub-like game in c++ (with HTML/CSS/JS frontend). In addition to human players making their moves, we'd like create an algorithm for making a move. 
Can someone recommend a good starting point, or an algorithm that already exists?

Answer (score 2):

In general, I'd say - on each step, examine the possible min distance from a full "hand" (that's not trivial), and try to give scores to the different pieces according to their use in possible solutions. Your ultimate goal is to decide which stone to throw that would minimize the risk of not being able to complete any of the possible end scenarios (possible bonus if you can interfere with your opponents, but that for later on I guess)

Answer (score 1):

For turn based games like this one minimax (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) is often used. To enable this algorithm with more than 2 players you would have each node be a vector of values, instead of a single value. This can lead to a huge number of computations, which you can remedy by applying alpha-beta pruning (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_beta_pruning) on the minimax tree.

As an aside: when working with AI for games, remember that your agents should be interesting to win over. It is (usually) very easy to make too difficult AI agents.